# Velocity Working with strings (String Split) - Problem

Tags: arrays, string, split, size, velocity

I am working with velocity (in Polarion - don't know whether it matters). And I am trying to split a sting into pieces. But it does not seem to work.

```
#set ($myString ="This.is.my.dummy.text") 
#set ($myArray = $myString.split('[.]'))

myString: $myString <br>
myString.class: $myString.class <br>
myArray: $myArray. <br>
myArray.class: $myArray.class <br>
myArray.length: $myArray.length() <br>
myArray.size: $myArray.size() <br>
myArray.get: $myArray.get(1) <br>


#foreach ($tmp in $myArray)
    tmp: $tmp <br>
#end
```

The output of my code is this:

```
myString: This.is.my.dummy.text
myString.class: class java.lang.String
myArray: [Ljava.lang.String;@5f41d583.
myArray.class: class [Ljava.lang.String;
myArray.length: $myArray.length()
myArray.size: $myArray.size()
myArray.get: $myArray.get(1)
tmp: This
tmp: is
tmp: my
tmp: dummy
tmp: text
```

myArray seems to be correct. My Questions:

- How do I access the size / length of the array?
- How do I access a particular Object (e.g. the third one).

Thanks

Jenny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Polarion Velocity you are severely limited as opposed to working in Java. To work in Polarion you may want to install the Wiki Scripting Extension, which introduces some very helpful objects into the Velocity scope: https://extensions.polarion.com/extensions/83-wiki-scripting-tools

This is a must-have for scripting in Polarion Velocity. You'll need these tools in many other instances as well.

Then you can write:

```
myArray.length: $listTool.size($myArray) <br>
myArray.get: $listTool.get($myArray, 1) <br>
```

Which results in:

```
myArray.length: 5 
myArray.get: is
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Velocity are you/Polarion using? With `2.3` version of `velocity-engine-core`, `$myArray.size()` does return the length of the array. To access the third element in the array, you can use `$myArray[2]` or `$myArray.get(2)`. According to the [Velocity docs](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#support-for-iterative-objects-for-foreach), Velocity internally wraps array in a List class, so methods like `size()` and `get()` can be used on arrays as well. When I tested your template using a [tester](https://github.com/devatherock/velocity-template-tester) I wrote which uses Velocity 2.3, I got the below result:

```
myString: This.is.my.dummy.text <br>
myString.class: class java.lang.String <br>
myArray: [This, is, my, dummy, text]. <br>
myArray.class: class [Ljava.lang.String; <br>
myArray.length: $myArray.length() <br>
myArray.size: 5 <br>
myArray.get: is <br>


    tmp: This <br>
    tmp: is <br>
    tmp: my <br>
    tmp: dummy <br>
    tmp: text <br>
```